# What is the maximum size of docker Image allowed on AKS?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

What is the maximum allowed Docker image size for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)?
For Azure Container Instance the max allowable docker image size is 15 GB.
But I could not find any documentation for AKS limit that covers max allowable docker image size. Any feedback or documentation in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no explicit limit on the container image size, but large images with large unique layers are likely to create containers with a large memory footprint, potentially exceeding [resource limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers) or the overall available memory of worker nodes (7 GiB for a [Standard_DS2_v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series) VM, which is currently the default in an AKS node pool).

If a container image is *excessively* large (TBs), kubelet might not be able to pull it from the registry to a node due to lack of disk space.

Comment: Thanks Max. So you are saying VM memory will be sort of limit? Which is one of the parameter for consideration and choose larger VM size to accomodate large docker images?

Comment: You'd look at the node pool in Azure, but did you actually run out of memory on a node? It seems more likely that you're hitting an explicit resource limit at the namespace or pod level.